# how to check the textarea content is blank using javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea

using `value.length != 0` ..doesn't work for the blank space situation

Comment: This demonstrates the importance of posting *actual code*. If you mistyped `lenght` in your code, that might be why it's not working. If your code is spelled correctly, please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jquery and use its `trim()` feature. If someone is inputting spaces, value will be neither `null` nor `length == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (value.match (/\S/)) { ... }
```

It will make sure `value` has at least 1 non-whitespace character

Answer (score 2):

```
document.myForm.myField.value != ""; // or
document.myForm.myField.value.length == 0;
```

Example:

```
function isEmpty() {
  alert(document.myForm.myField.value == "");
}
```

--

```
<button onclick="isEmpty()">Is Empty?</button>
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myField" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you clearly already know how to get the value, I'll skip that bit.

```
var value; // we'll assume it's defined
if(value) {
    // textarea content is not empty
} else {
    // textarea content is empty
}
```

`''` evaluates to false. Seems simple enough. What blank space situation are you talking about?