# Textarea Empty check

Tags: javascript, textarea

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validate();" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function validate()
{
         if(document.getElementById('details').value == '') 
         {      
        alert("Please Provide Details!");
              document.getElementById('details').focus();
        return false;       
        }
         else if(document.getElementById('name').value == '')
         {      
        alert("Please Provide Name!");
               document.getElementById('name').focus();
        return false;       
        }
         else
           return true;
}
```

OR

```
function validate()
    {
             if(document.myForm.details.value == '') 
             {      
            alert("Please Provide Details!");
              document.myForm.details.focus();
            return false;       
            }
             else if(document.myForm.name.value == '')
             {      
            alert("Please Provide Name!");
              document.myForm.name.focus();
            return false;       
            }
             else
               return true;
    }
```

I have seen the codes from previous Stack Overflow but as I am using these and it is not working. Will anyone help to solve check empty Value on Textarea using Javascript but not jquery.

The Reference I have used
[how to check the textarea content is blank using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090869/how-to-check-the-textarea-content-is-blank-using-javascript)
And
[How to check if a Textarea is empty in Javascript or Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476382/how-to-check-if-a-textarea-is-empty-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: It should work FINE!, you must have other errors in you page. Setup a demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: its working fine!!! check if other error exist in your page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may have space problem on your textarea. Use a trim function to reduce that. Here is the example following. I hope it may solve your problem.

JavaScript Add this function

```
function trimfield(str) 
{ 
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); 
}
```

And your JavaScript function

```
function validate()
{
     var obj1 = document.getElementById('details');
     var obj2 = document.getElementById('name');
         if(trimfield(obj1.value) == '') 
         {      
              alert("Please Provide Details!");
              obj1.focus();
              return false;       
         }
         else if(trimfield(obj2.value) == '')
         {      
               alert("Please Provide Name!");
               obj2.focus();
               return false;       
        }
         else
           return true;
}
```

OR

```
function validate()
    {
         var obj1 = document.myForm.details;
         var obj2 = document.myForm.name;
             if(trimfield(obj1.value) == '') 
             {      
               alert("Please Provide Details!");
               obj1.focus();
               return false;       
             }
             else if(trimfield(obj2.value) == '')
             {      
               alert("Please Provide Name!");
               obj2.focus();
               return false;       
             }
             else
               return true;
    }
```

And HTML with PHP

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validate();" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following jQuery to escape white spaces.

```
if($("#YourTextAreaID").val().trim().length < 1)
{
    alert("Please Enter Text...");
    return; 
}
```